# Implementing SOLR.Net and LUCENE.Net

Tags: c#, solr, lucene, lucene.net, solrnet

We want to implement full document search in our project in **.Net web project**.

For that we came across 2 names and below is what I deduced/inferred.

*Lucene.Net* is good at indexing and searching text, while *SOLR.Net* is at parsing multitude of documents.

I am not sure if *Lucene.Net*, *SOLR.Net* requires JRE to be present on the server as I do not know if they still use *Lucene* and/or *SOLR* internally (Java Versions).

So here are my 2 questions:

- Do I require JRE installed on my servers?
- How can I go with implementing search using *SOLR.Net*? i.e if it is dll based (API) or I need to do something else.

Comment: Is Question 2 missing?

Comment: it was there but it got merged in same line.

Comment: Grand just wondered encase you didn't get the full answer you were looking for.

Comment: got kind of. asked some more info in the answered section below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Solr` sits on top of `Lucene` and it is written in `Java`, so it requires `JRE`. 
`Solr.Net` is only `.net` client for `Solr`, so you would need host `Solr` somehow for it.

`Lucene` on the other hand originally was written in `Java`, but was ported to `.NET`, so you can simply reference dll of ported `Lucene` lib and you will be fine.

There is also `ElasticSearch`, that also sits on top of `Lucene` and it is also written in `Java`, so it requires `JRE` also, but it is better than `Solr` in several aspects, mainly in easier scaling, also has in my opinion better .net client.

Depending on that you need, you may also take a look at `RavenDB` and it also sits on top of `Lucene` and has full text search/faceting capabilities, may run on its own server or as embedded database (it is written in .net).

To answer your questions:

1) For `Lucene` only, you don't need `JRE`, we're running website using `Lucene.NET` on `Windows Azure Websites`, which means we haven't installed anthing additional on those server instances.

2) To use `Solr` for full text search, you need to:

1) Install `Solr` (you'll need `Servlet Container` to host `Solr`, I've tried only with `Tomcat`, `Solr` examples use `Jetty`) http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall. Alternatively you can outsource `Solr` hosting, for example from here: http://www.websolr.com/plans

2) Use some API (Solr.net) to add documents to index

3) Use some API (Solr.net) to perform search on index

Comment: What if I want to go by .Net only. Do I have some options in open source or I will have to get some third party java plugin as well.

Comment: Or any plugin for lucene.net which is also pure .net based with no req of java based something.

Comment: if you need simple stuff, there's not too much documents, you don't need scaling - you can go with lucene only and in such case it will be as easy to set up as install nuget pacage (there's also lucene contrib lib: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/ - for example if you need faceting). There are several wrappers for lucene - like https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleLucene/ or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Linq/ - they are great in some cases, but I've used lucene without any wrapper and had no problem.

Comment: that is the problem, I have only documents that also in thousands on daily basis.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is really hard to give any suggestion without knowing lots of facts about context - document count, analyzers to be used, document structure/analysed fields, search tools, etc. On SSD drive lucene is able to index ~150Gb/hour of plain text, respond to ~30 termqueries per second - all this of course depend a lot on configuration and data, so even if you have thousands of documents on daily basis, it does not mean, that lucene won't be enough.

Comment: But as per above information lucene does not parse documents by itself rather solr parses the document and gives body(content) which can then be used in lucene to index.

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly what you're saying, but in general if you'll use Lucene.Net.Linq you can add indexing attributes to existing class properties - so you deserialize that class from xml and index it, in my opinion it is pretty much the same as in Solr.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for all your effort. Thanks again.

Comment: A tad `over the top` with the `code blocks` for things that `aren't` code?